# A part of TextView content is not visible

Tags: android, layout, view

android is seeming to chop off my textviews for no reason.

The XML which surrounds the area is this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/suggestions">
        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And I'm programmatically adding the TextViews as follows:

```
LinearLayout suggestions = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.suggestions);
suggestions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
suggestions.removeAllViews();
for(String completion : completions){
    TextView show = new TextView(DailyboothBoothView.this);
    show.setTag(completion + " ");
    show.setText("@" + completion);
    show.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Some code here   
        }
    });
    show.setHeight(show.getLineHeight() + 10);
    show.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#cc6600"));
    suggestions.addView(show);
}
```

Comment: Sorry off topic, but are you using VMWare to run an android image? Can you pipe the apk straight from eclipse and install it in the VMware?

Comment: Yup! http://blog.gokifu.com/2011/05/android-x86-faster-emulator/ It's really awesome and super duper fast! :D

Comment: Awesome! I am going to install this right now! Thanks :)

Comment: You'll probably need to install Button Saviour, otherwise using stuff like Menu is a pain. (download the APK + in terminal roughly put `adb install APK.apk`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the view do the measuring and remove that `show.setHeight(show.getLineHeight() + 10)`
. It looks like TextView has some kind of internal extra padding before the first line of text which you do not take into account.

Comment: I added that line in the first place because it was being chopped off

Comment: Okay, something else I noticed is that you use layout_weight="1" in the HorizontalScrollView. Maybe the text is chopped off simply because there is not enough space for the HorizontalScrollView. Because the keyboard is open.

Comment: Before this wouldn't work, but using Alexander's answer combined with this works well :) and it's now looking as good as it should be! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
suggestions.addView(show);
```

with:

```
suggestions.addView(show, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```